# How to assign multiple users to a test plan in Kiwi TCMS?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have a team of 8-10 testers working on the same product. I want to use Kiwi TCMS as test management tool, we really liked it.

However, I am facing an issue to assign multiple testers to same test plan so that they all can execute and update the test cases. As of now there is an option to assign default tester which accepts only one user.

Answer (score 0):

You will create a new TestPlan and you can assign individual default testers for each TestCase. Then you create a TestRun.

On the dashboard users will see TestRuns if they are assigned to them, managed by them or there are TestCases inside these test runs assigned to them.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any way to assign multiple testers at test plan level as in our company testers are free to choose any test case they want to execute?

Comment: Not at the moment. You will have to describe your use-case in more details for us to consider if this is a viable feature request or not.  Please open a new issue on GitHub linking to this SO thread and vice versa and we can continue the discussion on GitHub. Thanks.